# UITableView dequeue cell is taking over 0.05 seconds

Tags: ios, uitableview, lag

I am dequeuing custom `UITableViewCells` and the amount of time it takes is astronomical on iPod 5th generation , causing severe laggyness and really bad performance

Here is my datasource code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CFTimeInterval startTimeInterval = CACurrentMediaTime();
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        NSString *identifier = nil;

        if (indexPath.section == RecentUserSection)
        {
            identifier = recentContactCellIdentifier;
        } else if (indexPath.section == GroupsSection) {
            identifier = contactCellIdentifier;
        } else if (indexPath.section == InboxNotificationSection)
        {
            identifier = inboxNotificationCellIdentifier;
        } else {
            identifier = contactCellIdentifier;
        }

        CFTimeInterval startDequeue = CACurrentMediaTime();
        ContactsViewControllerTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; // this is taking 0.05 second
        CFTimeInterval dequeueDuration = CACurrentMediaTime() - startDequeue;

        CFTimeInterval getUserStart = CACurrentMediaTime();
        id user = [[self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        CFTimeInterval getUserDuration= CACurrentMediaTime() - getUserStart;

        CFTimeInterval setUserStart = CACurrentMediaTime();
        cell.user = user;
        CFTimeInterval setUserDuration = CACurrentMediaTime() - setUserStart;
        cell.panDelegate = self;
        cell.auxillaryActionsDelegate = self;

        CFTimeInterval duration = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTimeInterval;

        if (duration > 0.016)
        {
            DLog(@"Not realtime - duration = %lf",duration);
            DLog(@"\ndequeue duration = %lf,\nget user duration = %lf,\nset user duration = %lf",dequeueDuration,getUserDuration,setUserDuration);
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Here is an example log

```
dequeue duration = 0.055643,
get user duration = 0.000025,
set user duration = 0.002490
```

All of my cells implement `prepareForReuse` and the average time for that is :

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    DLog(@"Reusing tableview cell");
    //doing stuff
    CFTimeInterval duration = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTimeInterval;
    DLog(@"Prepare for reuse time is %lf",duration);


}
```

log output

```
Prepare for reuse time is 0.001048
```

So it must be something internal to the `UITableView` - is there anything I can do about it? I don't understand why it is so slow on iPod but on iPhone it works very quickly

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is that you're doing too much calculation/computation when displaying cells. The most common cause of this is greedy image loading in UITableViewCells. If your cells contain images you should be doing some form of lazy loading.

If your data is coming form an API then the retrieval should be asynchronous, but I doubt this is an issue here because it runs fine on iPhone. If there are no images being rendered in the cells then it could be caused by CPU bogging graphic effects, but again I doubt this is the cause because the delay likely would not occur in in the dequeue function.

Comment: That could be- but I don't understand why the particual action would take so long  - I could understand if there was a method fetching an image on the main queue but that isn't the case - Does dequeueing a cell implecitaly "reload" a cell ?